# Are item creation feats worth it for a magus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have a level 2 Myrmidarch Magus that will eventually be Myrmidarch Magus 10 / Arcane Archer 10 and am focusing on blasting spell (you know, standard stuff for this build).

I recently found that feats come once every 2 levels instead of 3, which makes me think I could get some item creation feats, but because of my limited casting abilities I would not have access to all goodies that come to, say, a wizard.

Now there is another magus and a cleric in the party but they, as meleers need their feats so I am the only one considering it.

A dude told me to get scribe scroll and keep level 1-2 buffs in scroll form, but as an archer, I would have trouble using them with a bow in the hand. Potions are fine but since I will get mostly blasting spells, I wouldn't want to drink fireballs :)

While I would most certainly invest my available time into my own gear should I get magic item creation feats, I could, in the extra time or perhaps due to lack of gold, create gear for the rest of my party, which are melee magus dervish dancer, cleric tank and dwarven fighter with 3 levels dip of inquisitor. So I would love arguments for the feats in my build to aid them, at the end of the day.

Using Paizo only from their website.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time with what "is it worth it?" means to you. That's a subjective question, but you didn't give any criteria to try and go by. I can tell you why I think Item Creation Feats are good, but need more to do much else.

Comment: Is there any other feat you find interesting ? Which ones ? What books are you using ?

Comment: Scribe scroll might be worth it, perhaps the feat to enchant weapons and armor. Like I said, potions might be a bad choice for me as a ranged magus.

Comment: In general, Craft Wondrous Item is the most widely-useful feat, since it covers (by far) the most items; as a melee character, and Craft Magic Arms & Armor *will* save you a fair amount of money since you’ll be sinking a lot of money in that direction, but beyond that things tend to be getting very niche. I’d probably take Craft Wand over Scribe Scroll, I suppose. But in all cases you are trading feats for gp, which is rarely a very-good trade.

Comment: This is going to heavily depend on the world that the GM runs and how much money/loot/magic item shops are available

Comment: @Rob Money is standard, loot is totally random and there are no magic shops other than the one in the capitol.